# Animation stutter in Java's 2D rendering engine when object is moving fast

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, game-engine, graphics2d

I have been making a simple game in Java's 2D rendering engine and stumbled upon a problem, where if an object is moving fast enough, the animation will stutter every couple seconds or so.
I want to make it more smooth, so that the animation doesn't seem low quality.

This is my Main class run method:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    this.requestFocus();

    long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
    double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
    double delta = 0;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int frames = 0, ticks = 0;

    long renderLastTime = System.nanoTime();
    double amountOfRenders = 60;
    double renderNs = 1000000000 / amountOfRenders;
    double renderDelta = 0;

    while (isRunning) {
        long now = System.nanoTime();
        delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
        lastTime = now;
        while (delta >= 1) {
            tick();
            ticks++;
            delta--;
        }

        now = System.nanoTime();
        renderDelta += (now - renderLastTime) / renderNs;
        renderLastTime = now;
        while (isRunning && renderDelta >= 1) {
            render();
            frames++;
            renderDelta--;
        }

        if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000) {
            timer += 1000;
            FPS = frames;
            UPS = ticks;
            frames = 0;
            ticks = 0;
        }
    }
    stop();
}
```

If you need any more code, please comment.

Please help me out, so i can make this game more smooth!

Kind regards,
JulekPL

Comment: Looks like you are using a busy-wait. Instead, use a javax.swing.Timer instead.

Comment: How can i implement this? I am new to creating games in Java.

Comment: There are loads of tutorials available, Just search the web, now that you know what to search for,

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out. I don't know how to do it. @JustanotherJavaprogrammer

Comment: Did you find any tutorial?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Nope, just stack overflow posts and youtube videos about creating a stopwatch

Comment: I googled on "javax swing timer tutorial". The tutorial from oracle is good.

Comment: Ok, I'll contact you when I make it working.